# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullcallendar is not a function

Tags: fullcalendar

Já tentei de tudo para fazer o `fullcalendar` funcionar, meu código está assim :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Calendario";
    //Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<h2>Calendario</h2>
<div id='calendar' style="width:100%"></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#calendar').fullcallendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next,Hoje',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaweek,agendaday'
                },
                defaultview: 'agendaday',
                editable: true,
                alldayslot: false,
                selectable: true,
                slotminutes: 15,
            });
        });
 </script>
```

Sempre que executo, recebo a seguinte mensagem :

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullcallendar is not a function

Alguém pode me ajudar? Não sei se está faltando algum arquivo para mapear, ou se estou utilizando alguma biblioteca errada .

Answer (score 0):

Há um erro de digitação, você digitou:

`$('..').fullcallendar`

O correto, é com C maiúsculo e apenas um l em calendar:

`$('...').fullCalendar`